# how to impliment Notifications aggregation

Tags: android, notifications

My application displays event notifications, and I'm looking for a way to have notification aggregation.
Meaning, I would like to show 4 notification, but if the fifth comes, I would like to collect all notifications and show only one general notification.

Os there a way to know how many live notifications i have?
Is it possible to approach these notification and cancel them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the android design [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) you should stack your notifications. So you should avoid showing multiple notification for the same app.

You can stack your notifications using

`NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification)` where you specify same ID for each notification.

You can check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Updating) on how to implement it.

For your case

```
Is there a way to know how many live notifications i have - No
```

But you can keep a track of the notifications using Shared Preferences, where you store the ID of the notificaion and remove it when the user clicks on the notificaion

```
Is it possible to approach these notification and cancel them? - Yes
```

You can cancel a notification using the `cancel(int id)` method, where you pass the ID of the notification to be removed.

So you can use this method to acheive what you want, but it advisable to stack all the notifications.